# how to do coding in systems where msdos is the only operating system

Tags: c++, dos

I am experimenting something with the system which has MSDOS as the only operating system. I want to know how to do coding with command prompt, which is the only working environment provided by DOS. I want to write some c++ program. how can i write, compile and run  them.

Comment: If you want to write C++ programs, then please don't use other irrelevant language tags.

Comment: As for your "problem", first of all you do *know* C++? Have you ever coded a simple ["Hello World"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) program? Then you already know how to output to a "command prompt". There are also a few compilers available that can target DOS, but you have to search for them yourself (asking about that is off-topic).

Comment: This question is a bit too broad and also a tool recommendation question, which is off-topic here. In addition, I have bad news for you: there were never any C++ compilers made for MS DOS. C++ was standardized in 1998, and at that point companies had already stopped releasing DOS compilers. At best you can find a pre-standard compiler, which is a very bad idea. You will pick up bad practice.

Comment: Why ? Just why ?

Comment: fyi (not serious) you can use `CFront` with your "choice" of `C` backend see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront

Comment: You'd need a compiler that targets dos, i've had some good experiences with the watcom compiler (free), though there are others (such as old versions of the borland suite)